# Enable/Disable controls on ComboBox selection in Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to enable /disable controls like textbox,label,textblock if combobox is selected/not-selected? e.g. If selected index is greater than zero, enable controls else disable.How to bind IsEnabled properties of the control with combobox selection?

Comment: You bind the IsEnabled

Comment: @Paparazzi I've updated question.

Comment: In the `PropertyChanged` event of the ComboboxSelection you would need to update some other property in your **VM** that is bound to the `IsEnabled` property of the control(s) you want to enable/disable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can bind `IsEnabled` to the `SelectedIndex` property of the ComboBox and use a `IValueConverter` to convert it to Boolean. For instance, in your XAML (showing enabling a `Button`):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataList}}"/>
<Button Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cmbBox, Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource IndexToBoolConverter}}"/>
```

Then you need a converter as well, such as:

```
public class IndexToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int)value > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You'll also have declare the Converter as a resource, such as in your Window.

```
<local:IndexToBoolConverter x:Key="IndexToBoolConverter"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

I would probably just do something like this.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, 
                                               ElementName=TheCombo}" 
                                               Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <ComboBox x:Name="TheCombo" Width="100">
            <ComboBoxItem>Blah</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Blah</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Blah</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>

        <Button Content="Click Me" Margin="0,10"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ToggleButton dropDownButton = GetFirstChildOfType<ToggleButton>(cboMedicos);
                if (dropDownButton != null)
                {
                    dropDownButton.IsEnabled = false;
                }

            }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);


    public static T GetFirstChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (dependencyObject == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetFirstChildOfType<T>(child);

            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```