# How to make disable expander on combobox selection in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Actully I'm new to wpf. I want to disable expander on combobox selection. when selected index = 0 then expander should be disable else enable.
[I tried this both suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813341/enable-disable-controls-on-combobox-selection-in-xaml) but in first answer I'm getting error at this. line ==>

```
<local:IndexToBoolConverter x:Key="IndexToBoolConverter"/>
```

and in second answer but it disturbing Look (style) of the expander.

My Xaml code is :

```
      <UserControl x:Class="ABC.UI.Pages.Scan.Create.Base"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                     xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"

                     mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="500">

            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="ExpanderDriven" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex,
                                                       ElementName=ComboboxMode}"
                                                       Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="ExpanderDriven1" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex,
                                                       ElementName=ComboboxMode}"
                                                       Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>

 <Expander Name="ExpanderDriven1" Header="Driven properties" Margin="0 5 0 0" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDriven}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cmbBox, Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource IndexToBoolConverter}}"
                          BorderBrush="{DynamicResource WindowBorder}"
                          Background="{DynamicResource WindowBorder}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid>

                            <Label Content="Driving Tag" />
</Grid> </StackPanel></Expander>
```

Comment: what exactly does error message say?

Comment: @vasily.sib 
Error XLS0414 The type 'local:IndexToBoolConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. ABC.UI Base.xaml 14 
Error XDG0008 The name "IndexToBoolConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ABC.Resources.Language;assembly=ABC.Resources".

Comment: that means, that class `ABC.Resources.Language.IndexToBoolConverter` was not found in assembly `ABC.Resources`. Are you sure, that this class exists? Try to rebuild entire solution.

Comment: Yes I added but still showing this Errors >> Error XDG0008 The name "IndexToBoolConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ABC.UI.Helper". ABC.UI Base.xaml 14 
Error XDG0036 The "Key" attribute can only be used on an element that is contained in "IDictionary". ABC.UI Base.xaml 14 
Error XLS0509 Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content. They must be before or after the content. ABC.UI Base.xaml 40 
Error XLS0503 A value of type 'IndexToBoolConverter' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'. ABC.UI Base.xaml 14

Comment: @vasily.sib actually I don't understand where to add this line <local:IndexToBoolConverter x:Key="IndexToBoolConverter"/> exactly.

Comment: this is because you need to add it to `ResourceDictionary` like this: `<UserControl.Resources><local:IndexToBoolConverter x:Key="IndexToBoolConverter"/></UserControl.Resources>`

Comment: @vasily.sib Oh thank you so much. Its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you need to add it to ResourceDictionary like this:

`<UserControl.Resources><local:IndexToBoolConverter x:Key="IndexToBoolConverter"/></UserControl.Resources>`

Answer By – @vasily.sib

and its working!